# QRegular expression

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I can't find a way to match the text before opening curly bracket (i.e. p) using regex and Qt. My input file reads :

```
  solvers 
  { 
      p
      { 
          solver          PCG; 
          preconditioner  DIC; 
          tolerance       1e-06; 
          relTol          0.05; 
      }

      q
      {
          solver          PCG;
          relTol          0.03;
      }
   }
```

and corresponding code from .cpp is :

```
rule.pattern = QRegularExpression("\\b(\\w+)(?=[\\s+\n]?\\{)",
                                  QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
```

Is anyone with better knowledge of Qt and regex can explain to me a way to achieve that?

---

### EDIT #1

Thanks for the reply and comment. Two things :

- I mistype my input file had no ">" symbol so I edited it in the above completed input.
- I was trying to match the "p" of p-block and the "q" of q-block. A more extended version of my input is now edited above.

I found   [\}\s*(\w+)(?=\s*\{)](https://regex101.com/r/HABgc0/5)  to matched the "q" q-block but does not work in the code. 
It seems to struggle with the return to line between "p" and the bracket "{".

---

### EDIT #2 : show the code

in highlighter.cpp

```
  #include "highlighter.h"

Highlighter::Highlighter(QTextDocument *parent)
    : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)
{
    HighlightingRule rule;
    (...)
    varFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
    varFormat.setForeground(Qt::darkMagenta);
    rule.pattern = QRegularExpression("^\\s+(\\w+)\\s*$",QRegularExpression::MultilineOption);
    rule.format = varFormat;
    highlightingRules.append(rule);
 (...) }  


void Highlighter::highlightBlock(const QString &text)
{
    foreach (const HighlightingRule &rule, highlightingRules) {
        QRegularExpressionMatchIterator matchIterator = rule.pattern.globalMatch(text);
        while (matchIterator.hasNext()) {
            QRegularExpressionMatch match = matchIterator.next();
            setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), rule.format);
        }
    }
    setCurrentBlockState(0);

    int startIndex = 0;
    if (previousBlockState() != 1)
        startIndex = text.indexOf(commentStartExpression);

    while (startIndex >= 0) {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = commentEndExpression.match(text, startIndex);
        int endIndex = match.capturedStart();
        int commentLength = 0;
        if (endIndex == -1) {
            setCurrentBlockState(1);
            commentLength = text.length() - startIndex;
        } else {
            commentLength = endIndex - startIndex
                            + match.capturedLength();
        }
        setFormat(startIndex, commentLength, multiLineCommentFormat);
        startIndex = text.indexOf(commentStartExpression, startIndex + commentLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: And are you trying to get just `solvers`? Replace `(?=[\\s+\n]?\\{)` with `(?=\\s*{)` and remove `QRegularExpression::MultilineOption`, it is redundant. Or, keep the modifier, and use `QRegularExpression("^>\\s*\\K\\w+(?=\\s*{)")`

Comment: Thanks for all the solution. It seems that QRegularExpression is something like PRCE but not entirely. Indeed all your solution works fine on [link]regex101.com but not once compiled.  For now, I go with `^\\s+(\\w+)\\s*$` with the multiline option, which select the text I wanted to be selected (and other if indent errors are present)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you trying to get `.captured(1)`? Use `.captured(0)` with my regex.

Comment: I mean that it does not match the text I matched on [regex101.com].

Comment: Ok, I will adjust the answer to work with a capturing group.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Comment: And Kudos for the code posted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `[\\s+\n]?`, it matches 1 or 0 occurrences of any whitespace or `+` characters. But there are more than 1 whitespace betwee `solvers` and `{`.

Replacing `(?=[\\s+\n]?\\{)` with `(?=\\s*{)` will already fix the issue. But you may also use

```
QRegularExpression("^\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\\{", QRegularExpression::MultilineOption)
```

to match the

- `^` - start of a line
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\\w+)` - Group 1 (you can get it via `match.captured(1)`): one or more word chars
- `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces followed with
- `\{` - a literal `{`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HABgc0/8).

Answer (score 0):

Because p is not after {, but is after }

You can go this way:
`[\{\}]\s*(\w+)(?=\s*\{)` see https://regex101.com/r/wA1vu2/3

Or this this one:
`(?P<tagname>[^{}\s]*)(?P<postspace>\s*)(?P<json_item>\{[^{}]*\})`

- `?P<tagname>` name of the match
- `?P<json_item>\{[^{}]*\}` - leaf level item
- `(?P<postspace>\s*)` - space between leaf item and leaf name
- `(?P<tagname>[^{}\s]*)` - leaf name

https://regex101.com/r/wA1vu2/1/